# Name for a user dropdown, user preference dropdown, preference dropdown, settings dropdown, language selection dropdown

Tags: dropdown, drop-down-list, jquery

How is this type of dropdown used in Amazon called?

[image: amazon dropdown select]

It basically permits you to select among a selection list and then it auto submits your selection via jquery and retains it for the rest of the session.
In the case of Amazon EC2 you select the country of your server and all the rest of the menus are relative to that country.

If someone can suggest a name for this concept and other notorious examples of sites which use it.

**EDIT**: language selection is a very common case of this kind of dropdown by the way.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of language selection, we're talking about localization, so I would suggest that it is a 'localization dropdown', 'localization navigation' or something along those lines. Neither of those sound particularly snappy though. Hope this helps.

Comment: I was looking for a broader term, because this type of dropdown is often used for other types of preferences. "user preference dropdown" sounds more general..

Comment: I thought that might be the case. To borrow from Franchesca, what if it was just a 'preference dropdown'?

Comment: "preference dropdown" sounds even better, now the question: what are all possible periphrasis for this same concept so that people searching for it will find this thread and will consider using the word "preference dropdown"?

Comment: Phew, there's probably a lot of different permutations. I'm not sure if I'm phrasing these correctly, but I would suggest: 'user dropdown', 'user preference dropdown', 'preference dropdown', 'settings dropdown', that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would think it falls under "user preference".

Comment: So you would name this dropdown a "user preference dropdown"? this sounds like something..

Comment: @dendini Yes. I think Localization sounds more like a choice that is imposed upon the user, like when I go to a .com website and it sends me to a .nl website with language in Dutch, purely based on location (annoying when you are an expat).